# How would one find the sum of the following question using poisson properties?

Tags: statistics

I don't really have any idea how to approach this question. I can't manipulate it to resemble poisson.

$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^x}{x!}$

Comment: Almost the same way as in [this other question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496055/using-distribution-properties-to-find-the-exact-value).

Comment: (also, what do you know about the Poisson distribution? This does not need much "manipulating" to look like something very close to the sum of probabilities of a Poisson distribution.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The probability mass function of a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda > 0$ is $p(k) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Further hint #1:**

> the sum of all probabilities is $1$, i.e. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty p(k) =1$.

**Further hint #2:**

> This is exactly saying $e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} =1$, i.e. $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} =e^\lambda$$ for any $\lambda > 0.$ (actually, this equality holds for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, but that is not relevant here.)